# Is it possible to make kernel resolve symbols in a stack trace?

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb

I have a program that crashes from time to time with the following message in syslog. The program does not have SIGSEGV handler implemented, so the stack trace below is generated by the kernel.

What interests me: Is this possible to make the kernel to resolve these userspace addresses, so function names/lines are visible instead?

```
# /tmp/prog
prog[10159]: unhandled level 3 permission fault (11) at 0x557e8a3a10, esr 0x9200004f                                                     
 pgd = ffffffc03a7e5000                                                                                                                  
 [557e8a3a10] *pgd=0000000018c95003, *pud=0000000018c95003, *pmd=000000002fffe003,                                                       
557e8a3000-557e8a4000 r-xp 00000000 00:13 267223  /tmp/prog                                                                              
557e8b3000-557e8b4000 r--p 00000000 00:13 267223  /tmp/prog                                                                              
557e8b4000-557e8b5000 rw-p 00001000 00:13 267223  /tmp/prog                                                                              
7f8ae78000-7f8afad000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 642     /lib/libc-2.26.so                                                                      
7f8afad000-7f8afbc000 ---p 00135000 08:02 642     /lib/libc-2.26.so                                                                      
7f8afbc000-7f8afc0000 r--p 00134000 08:02 642     /lib/libc-2.26.so                                                                      
7f8afc0000-7f8afc2000 rw-p 00138000 08:02 642     /lib/libc-2.26.so                                                                      
7f8afc2000-7f8afc6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                              
7f8afc6000-7f8afe3000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 633     /lib/ld-2.26.so                                                                        
7f8afee000-7f8aff0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                              
7f8aff0000-7f8aff1000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0       [vvar]                                                                                 
7f8aff1000-7f8aff2000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0       [vdso]                                                                                 
7f8aff2000-7f8aff3000 r--p 0001c000 08:02 633     /lib/ld-2.26.so                                                                        
7f8aff3000-7f8aff5000 rw-p 0001d000 08:02 633     /lib/ld-2.26.so                                                                        
7fe37af000-7fe37d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0       [stack]                                                                                
                                                                                                                                         
CPU: 0 PID: 10159 Comm: prog Tainted: P           O    4.1.37.14                                                                         
task: ffffffc03a578ac0 ti: ffffffc02bd70000 task.ti: ffffffc02bd70000                                                                    
PC is at 0x557e8a395c                                                                                                                    
LR is at 0x7f8ae97b6c                                                                                                                    
pc : [<000000557e8a395c>] lr : [<0000007f8ae97b6c>] pstate: 60000000                                                                     
sp : 0000007fe37cef80                                                                                                                    
x29: 0000007fe37cef90 x28: 0000000000000000                                                                                              
x27: 0000000000000000 x26: 0000000000000000                                                                                              
x25: 0000000000000000 x24: 0000000000000000                                                                                              
x23: 0000000000000000 x22: 0000000000000000                                                                                              
x21: 000000557e8a3840 x20: 0000000000000000                                                                                              
x19: 000000557e8a3970 x18: 0000007fe37cf298                                                                                              
x17: 0000007f8ae97a90 x16: 000000557e8b3fa8                                                                                              
x15: 0000000000000003 x14: 0000000000000000                                                                                              
x13: 0000007f8aff3030 x12: 0000007f8aff3038                                                                                              
x11: 0000000000000404 x10: 0000008000080000                                                                                              
x9 : 00000000000fffff x8 : ffffffffffffffff                                                                                              
x7 : 0000000000000404 x6 : 0000000000000000                                                                                              
x5 : 0000000000000000 x4 : 0000007fe37cefe8                                                                                              
x3 : 000000557e8a3944 x2 : 0000007fe37cf0d8                                                                                              
x1 : 0000000000000048 x0 : 000000557e8a3a10                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                         
 Call trace:                                                                                                                             
[<000000557e8a395c>] 0x557e8a395c
```

The program looks like this:

```
int main() {                                                                                                                             
    const char *s = "hello world";                                                                                                       
    *(char *)s = 'H';                                                                                                                       
    return 0;                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Compiling using `gcc -g prog.c -o prog` or with `gcc -rdynamic prog.c -o prog` does not affect the stack trace

Comment: I suggest you create a core dump and load the core dump in gdb.

Comment: Technically you already have enough information to calculate the offset of PC into `/tmp/prog` and then use `objdump` or similar to find out what that offset matches ... but using a core file is _much_ easier. That's what they're for.

Comment: This isn't a _kernel_ stack trace -- it's _user process_ stack trace. The title of your question is all wrong, as is the `linux-kernel` tag.

Comment: You could use systemtap (part of which runs in the kernel) or gdb to get symbolic stack traces. Is that all you need, or do you need the kernel to produce symbolic addresses in the syslog?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, yes, the latter: I'm wondering if this is possible to make kernel to produce symbolic addresses and if so, how to do this. Thanks for rephrasing it, I probably made the title a little bit confusing

Comment: I've found that it's quite straightforward to implement this: I just need to subtract offset I get in "r-xp" field (.text) from addresses in a stack trace -- that would be an actual address of the erroneous instruction, then I could just feed this to addr2line and get the desired output. But I need a kernel solution, so I'd start by  modifying `save_stack_trace_user()`

Answer (score 1):

It is ("technically") possible to do what you ask, but it is unlikely that a kernel maintainer will allow such functionality into a general purpose kernel.

It looks like you want to do this as a solution to some other problem. If it's simply a matter of logging the stack trace every time the program crashes, it can be addressed outside the kernel in many ways.

E.g. You can implement a SIGSEGV handler that will print out a stack trace to your liking, package it into a shared library (with an initializer to set up the signal handler) and load it into the program virtual address using `LD_PRELOAD` when launching the program.